# Surface 3 boot from USB

Tags: boot, usb, microsoft-surface

I'm trying to boot my surface 3 from a USB in order to install Xubuntu.

I have already held down <kbd>Volume up</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd> while booting in order to disable Secure Boot Control. I think went to Configure Alternate System Boot Order and selected Network -> USB -> SSD and then selected Exit Setup saved and restarted.

However, my surface still boots into Windows instead of from the USB. I tested the USB drive on my laptop and I could boot from it there with no problems.

I am writing the usb with the following: `sudo dd if=/media/kalenpw/HDD/ISOs/xubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso of=/dev/sdd`

Any help would be appreciated as googling has got me no where but people saying ensure secure boot is disabled and the drive is actually bootable, both of which I have done

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never.
Have you tried to disable "[Secure boot](https://www.onmsft.com/news/how-to-disable-secure-boot-on-surface-pro-devices)"?

*Disabling Secure Boot on Surface Pro will allow you to install other operating systems on your device*. Here’s how.

1. Power down your Surface Pro
2. Press and hold the volume-up button
3. Press and release the power button while holding down the volume up button
4. Release the volume up button when the Surface logo appears
5. **Select Secure Boot Control**
6. **Select Disable**
7. Select Exit Set up and then Yes
8. Now install alternate OS

As per the note at the end of [this article](https://www.onmsft.com/how-to/how-to-boot-from-a-usb-stick-on-surface-pro-devices) on onmsft.com

> NOTE: Remember to disable Secure Boot if you are attempting to install
>   any OS other than Windows 8.1 64-bit or later on your Surface Pro.
>   Otherwise, your Surface will simply ignore the USB installation drive.